# php preg_split seems to crash on large strings

Tags: php, large-files, preg-split

I have been trying to load the USDA nutritional data into a mysql database from the [ascii version of the data](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=22771). I used the scripts from [here](http://drupal.org/node/107806) and everything came in except the NUT_DATA.txt file which is ~34MB in size. The file loads correctly using the php script (so memory limits should not be an issue, they are set at 128M anyways) using the `file_get_contents` function. However, when it gets to the `preg_split('#\n#', $file)` line, the script ends without further comment. If I break the file into smaller pieces, it runs fine. Why does it not work on the full file? I have memory_limit set to 128M and upload_max_filesize set to 128M. The whole file seems to have been read in, it is just the `preg_split` that seems to be having problems.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks!

Here is the php code I have been testing with:

```
<?php
// from http://drupal.org/node/107806

//$dbh=mysql_connect(/*db info*/);
//mysql_select_db(/*db info*/);
try
{
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX');
  echo "PDO access worked! <br />";
} catch (PDOException $e)
{
  echo "PDO error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
  die();
}

//List of SR20 filenames with associated field counts.
$filenames = array(//"DERIV_CD" => 2,
//        "FD_GROUP" => 2,
//        "NUTR_DEF" => 6,
//        "SRC_CD" => 2,
//        "WEIGHT" => 7,
//        "FOOTNOTE" => 5,
//        "DATA_SRC" => 9,
//        "DATSRCLN" => 3,
//        "FOOD_DES" => 14,
        "NUT_DATA" => 17
//        "NUT_DATA2" => 17,
//        "NUT_DATA_test" => 17
     );
foreach($filenames as $filename => $count) {
    echo "inside foreach: $filename ";
    $file = file_get_contents($filename.'.txt');
    echo " read in the file, length = " . strlen($file) . "<br />";
    $lines = preg_split('#\n#', $file);
    echo "made it past preg_split <br />";
//    print_r($lines);
    echo " lines = " . count($lines). "<br />";
    for($i=0;$i<count($lines);++$i) {
        $line = $lines[$i];
//        echo "Inside for loop, line = '" . $line . "'<br />";
        //Some text fields are split over several lines. Concatenate them.
        while(substr_count($line, '^') < $count-1 || (substr_count($line, '~')%2) == 1) {
            ++$i;
            if($i>=count($lines)) { break; }
            $line .= '<br />'.$lines[$i];
        }
        $fields = trim($line);
        if(strlen($fields) == 0) continue;
        $fields = str_replace(array("'", '~', '^'), array("''", "'", ','), $fields);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `$filename` VALUES($fields);";
        //Insert zeroes for unfilled values.
        $sql = str_replace(array(',,', ',)'), array(',0,', ',0)'), $sql);
        $sql = str_replace(array(',,', ',)'), array(',0,', ',0)'), $sql);
        $sql = str_replace(array(',,', ',)'), array(',0,', ',0)'), $sql);
        //Some single-char fields aren't quoted.
        $sql = preg_replace('#,([A-Z])\);$#', ",'$1');", $sql);
// comment out the database interface until things are working
/*        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        if(!$stmt->execute()) 
        {
            echo $sql;
        }
*/
    }
}
echo "done";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the following two lines to the top of my php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

and it told me that it had run out of memory. Upping the memory again (to 256M) solved the issue. I guess I can't guess how much memory a task is going to use.

Answer (score -2):

Add this config into your httpd.conf

```
ThreadStackSize 8388608
```